# Custom Domain to Azure CDN Endpoint with and without www

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have created an Azure CDN, an endpoint and working fine.

Created a CNAME `www.mydomain.com` to `myazurecdn.azureedge.net`
Created another CNAME `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com`

In Azure Endpoint, Custom Domain, I updated `www.mydomain.com` and it got propagated.

Now, when I navigate to `www.mydomain.com`, everything works fine but when I navigate to `mydomain.com` i get below response.

> ### Our services aren't available right now
>
> We're working to
>   restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.

Note: As Azure endpoint accepts multiple custom domain, I could add both `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` but it is not correct way, as I have many `<a>` tags with `www.mydomain.com/link`.

What to be done now to instruct system to use same route for `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`?

Is domain redirect from `domain.com` to `www.mydomain.com` only option?

Comment: Strictly speaking you shouldn't be allowed to set a CNAME on mydomain.com because it is an "apex domain". Only sub-domains like www.mydomain.com can be CNAMEd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#create-a-cname-dns-record),

> **A custom domain and its subdomain can be associated with only a single
>   endpoint at a time.** However, you can use different subdomains from the
>   same custom domain for different Azure service endpoints by using
>   multiple CNAME records. You can also map a custom domain with
>   different subdomains to the same CDN endpoint.

You can use different subdomains in the same endpoint. Alternatively, I think you also could create two endpoints, one is for the root domain `without www`, the other is for a subdomain `with www`.

Comment: Yes, in such case, some users may in domain.com and some may in www.domain.com, I would to like be all my users in one route i.e www.domain.com, what is the right way?

Comment: If you just want all users to access the websites with one custom domain, why don't you directly create one endpoint with one subdomain i.e www.domain.com? Or, if you want all traffic route to www subdomain, try to configure the Azure CDN’s Rules Engine, the Azure CDN Profile must be the Premium Verizon pricing tier. See this Rule 2: Redirect Root to www https://arlanblogs.alvarnet.com/add-url-rewrite-rules-to-an-azure-content-delivery-network/

Answer (score -1):

I would say, you can implement redirection in your server or CDN.

When someone tries to access example.com, you can do a 301 by sending http://www.example.com in the location header.

Comment: Redirection from the server means DNS settings or in program? Whats the path at CDN?

Comment: I use Angular i am searching for such code, meanwhile can i know the path and steps in CDN.

Comment: @Ramesh, In Azure CDN you can use the rules engine to do a redirect